# Let $w \in G_{15}$ be a primitive root. Find every $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{i=2}^{n-1} w^{3i} = 0$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity, primitive-roots

We can first rewrite the series in a useful form,

$$\sum_{i=2}^{n-1} w^{3i} = \bigg( \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} w^{3i} \bigg) - w^3 - 1 $$

But since $w$ is primitive, we can apply the geometric series formula,

$$\frac{w^{3n} - 1}{w^3 - 1} - w^3 - 1 = 0 \ \iff \ w^{n} = w^2$$

So, the answer should be $n=2$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $w$ be a primitive $15$-th root of unity.

For $n\le 2$, the relation
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} w^{3k} = 0$$
holds trivially.

Suppose $n\in\mathbb{N}$, with $n > 2$.

Then as you derived,
$$\sum_{k=2}^{n-1} w^{3k} = 0\;\iff\;\frac{w^{3n}-1}{w^3-1}-w^3-1=0$$

Continuing from that result,
\begin{align*}
&\frac{w^{3n}-1}{w^3-1}-w^3-1=0\\[4pt]
\iff\;&\frac{w^{3n}-1}{w^3-1}=w^3+1\\[4pt]
\iff\;&w^{3n}-1=(w^3+1)(w^3-1)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&w^{3n}-1=w^6-1\\[4pt]
\iff\;&w^{3n}=w^6\\[4pt]
\iff\;&w^{3n-6}=1\\[4pt]
\iff\;&3n-6\equiv 0\;(\text{mod}\;15)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&3n\equiv 6\;(\text{mod}\;15)\\[4pt]
\iff\;&n\equiv 2\;(\text{mod}\;5)\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
hence, the set of qualifying values of $n$ is 
$$\{1\}\cup \{n\in\mathbb{N}\mid n\equiv 2\;(\text{mod}\;5)\}$$